# How do I know if Quirks mode was triggered within IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, quirks-mode

I read that if the DOCTYPE is not corectly set IE6 will enter Quirks mode.

I have given a document HTML 4.01 Transitional, but how do I know if IE6 triggers Quirks mode or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [document.compatMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533687%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  if(document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat'){
    alert("Standards mode");
  }else{
    alert("Quirks mode");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

create a bookmark with the following link:

javascript:m=(document.compatMode=='CSS+Compat')?'Standards.':'Quirks';window.alert('You are in ' + m + ' mode.');

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the end of the address bar, there is a little "broken page" icon that shows whether you are in quirks mode, or "proper" mode!

You can also get this using JavaScript by querying...

```
alert(document.compatMode);
```